# Gulp работа с FTP, vinyl FTP

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, scss, ftp

```js
// Основной модуль
import gulp from "gulp";
// Импорт путей
import { path } from "./gulp/config/path.js";
// Импорт общих плагинов
import { plugins } from "./gulp/config/plugins.js"

// Передаем значения в глобавльную переменную
global.app = {
    isBuild: process.argv.includes('--build'),
    isDev: !process.argv.includes('--build'),
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp,
    plugins: plugins
}

// Импорт задач
import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";
import { reset } from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
import { html } from "./gulp/tasks/html.js";
import { server } from "./gulp/tasks/server.js";
import { scss } from "./gulp/tasks/scss.js";
import { js } from "./gulp/tasks/js.js";
import { images } from "./gulp/tasks/images.js";
// import { otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle } from "./gulp/tasks/fonts.js";
import { svgSprive } from "./gulp/tasks/svgSprive.js";
import { zip } from "./gulp/tasks/zip.js";
import { ftp } from "./gulp/tasks/ftp.js";

// Наблюдатель за изменениями в файлах
function watcher() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy); // gulp.series(html, ftp)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, html);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, gulp.series(scss, ftp));
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, js);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.images, images);
}

export { svgSprive }

// Последовательность обработка шрифтов
// const fonts = gulp.series(otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle);

// Основные задачи
// const mainTasks = gulp.series(fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images));
const mainTasks = gulp.series(copy, html, scss, js, images);

// Построение сценариев выполнения задачи
const dev = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, gulp.parallel(watcher, server));
const build = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks);
const deployZIP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, zip);
const deployFTP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, ftp);

// Экспорт сценраиев
export { dev }
export { build }
export { deployZIP }
export { deployFTP }

// Выполнение сценария по умолчанию
gulp.task('default', dev);
```

по запросу npm run deploy выгружается файлы на сервер, а вот обновление не происходит, то есть когда изменяю стили, то эти обновлении стилей не происходит, как можно решить эту задачу?

второй вопрос:
допустим есть сайт на сервере и там есть файлы package.json/gulpfile.js, как можно запустить на локальном, чтоб все конвертации работали и передались изменение файлы на сервер

p.s gulp файл собрал из ролика
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU88mLuLWlk&t=5109s

там сказано, что работать обновление файлов на сервере, но не работает или я не правильно делаю

Answer (score 0):

Просто зарегистрируйте в watcher дополнительную команду для нужных типов файлов:

```
gulp.watch(path.build.css, ftp);
```